# Java and ADB(Send SMS using android messaging app via USB Tethering)

Tags: java, android, javafx, mobile-development

I am developing javafx application that will send sms using my android messaging app via USB Tethering and with ADB. I already enable USB Debuggin mode.
My code actually works, but it is only opening my android messaging app but not sending.
Below is my code:

```
package com.chanoc.textblaster;


import java.io.IOException;

public abstract class SendSMSThroughADB {

    public static void sendSMS(){
        String phone_number = "09101092252";
        String message = "Hello from java over ADB!";

        try{

            String command = "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:" + phone_number + " --es sms_body '"+ message +"'";

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("SMS successfully sent!");
        }catch(IOException|InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SMS failed to send!");
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is a big help. Thank you!!!